# reduce image size in bytes without resize and quality lose in c#

Tags: c#, image, optimization, jpeg

I m using C#.NET 4.0

I have an jpeg image and i want to reduce its size in bytes .I don't want to change the image size in manner of height and width and not want to lose image quality.Some bit of reduce quality is not an issue. I try to make it a thumbnail image but it reduce the size according to height and width.

I can't found any solution.
Any type help will be appreciated..

Comment: "and not want to lose image quality.Some bit of reduce quality is not an issue"  Is lossy compression acceptable or not?  It sounds like you're contradicting yourself.

Comment: reduce of quality at some degree(10-20%) is acceptable in video conferencing.But we can't reduce the quality more than that.Because it strech the image and n then images looks ugly. is it possible that we compress a image and decompress it on other side without losing quality ?I don''t know much about compression/decompression.

Answer (score 6):

Size reduction is generally accompanied by quality reduction. You cannot have it both ways.

Answer (score 1):

How about saving jpeg at 90% quality (which usually provides good quality of an image) and then comparing size with your original jpeg file. 
Something like this:
new jpeg < old jpeg ? new jpeg : old jpeg

Answer (score 0):

If you want reduce the image size then you have to trim the width and height, according to that only the size reduces unless it is not possible.