# Reduce Image size C#

Tags: c#, .net, image

My scenario:

i want to expect reduce image size (10 KB to 3 KB)

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933918/reduce-image-size-in-bytes-without-resize-and-quality-lose-in-c

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Well, what you want can be this :

```
// Make sure to include this at the top
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```

```
/// <summary> 
/// Saves an image as a jpeg image, with the given quality 
/// </summary> 
/// <param name="path"> Path to which the image would be saved. </param> 
/// <param name="quality"> An integer from 0 to 100, with 100 being the highest quality. </param> 
public static void SaveJpeg (string path, Image img, int quality) 
{ 
    if (quality<0  ||  quality>100) 
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("quality must be between 0 and 100."); 

     // Encoder parameter for image quality 
     EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality); 
     // JPEG image codec 
     ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg"); 
     EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1); 
     encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam; 
     img.Save(path, jpegCodec, encoderParams); 
} 

/// <summary> 
/// Returns the image codec with the given mime type 
/// </summary> 
private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mimeType) 
{ 
     // Get image codecs for all image formats 
     ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders(); 

     // Find the correct image codec 
     for(int i=0; i<codecs.Length; i++) 
         if(codecs[i].MimeType == mimeType) 
             return codecs[i]; 

     return null; 
 }
```

Then you can do this:

```
// First load the image somehow
Image myImage = Image.FromFile(pathToImage, true); 
// Save the image with a quality of 50% 
SaveJpeg (destImagePath, myImage, 50);
```

Refer to [this post on VB Forums](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?p=2038463) and [this blog post](http://geekswithblogs.net/bullpit/archive/2009/04/29/compress-image-files-using-c.aspx).

Comment: That's a perfect solution, reduced my image size from 5.5MB to 1.7MB with 70% quality.

Comment: I got "parameter is not valid" with the above code, I had to use a long value for the quality, not int as above which solved the issue.

Comment: Outstanding effort...

Answer (score 2):

[Use GDI](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/imageresize.aspx)

Please look at this sample. Use GDI+ to resize the photo. Wish it can help you.

Answer (score -12):

Well, images can't magically become smaller, so you will either have to compress it or scale it down.

Comment: Yes it can. By the magic of c#! Reduce the quality while maintaining scale. No compression needed.